# Covering an area equally with layers of non-tesselating polygons

Tags: geometry, tessellations

A series of hexagons on an hexagonal lattice means that the every point in the entire area is covered by one polygon only.

A grid of octagons will not tesselate, leaving square holes such that 4/18 of the area is not covered.

Is it possible to stack multiple layers of identical, non-tesselating, regular polygons such that every point in the area underneath is covered by the same number of integer polygons? e.g. every point being covered by *n* - *m* polygons from *n* layers of *k*-sided polygons spaced on a specified lattice (*m < n)*.

I have started by considering the case of the octagon grid. I don't think it is possible with this basis, as it would require being able to tesselate other squares around the square vacancies, which they cannot. Are other values of *k* viable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't require regular octagons, you can do it.  In the tessellation below, let the horizontal and vertical sides of the octagons be $1$ and the diagonal sides of the octagons be $\sqrt 2$.  Then the distance between squares is $3$ and the squares cover $\frac 18$ of the plane.  You can stack eight of these and cover each point seven times.  You can do a similar thing with the canonical dodecagon/equilateral triangle tiling-make the sides of the dodecagons that touch each other the proper value and the triangles will fill the plane.

[image]

Comment: Is it possible with larger n? Trying with dodecagons of alternating sides $1$ and $\sqrt 2$, the vacancies are equilateral triangles but the layering pattern requires squares and hexagons too. Is this conclusively not possible with regular polygons, $n > 6$?

Comment: On another look, I don't think you can do it with dodecagons and triangles alone.  There is such a tiling, but the triangles won't line up properly in both directions.

Comment: Is it possible with octagons of sides $1$ and $\frac {1.5}{\sqrt 2}$? This gives 2 full squares per octagon width plus a "remainder" of half a square. Placing 7 layers widthwise gives an overlap of 5 along this plane, but 7 elsewhere. This process can then be repeated in the other axis, to give 47 layers with 41 overlaps everywhere. The octagon-octagon sides would then be only 6.07% longer than the octagon-square sides.

Comment: Any time you get the spacing of the squares to be rational, which is when the diagonal sides of the octagon are a rational times $\sqrt 2$, you will be able to get even coverage.  I don't think your coverage is right.  The area of the octagon is $\frac {17}2$, so you need a multiple of $19$ layers giving the same multiple of $17$ times coverage.

Comment: Of course, the easiest rational multiple of $\sqrt 2$ to use is zero.  Then the octagons have the same area (and shape) as the squares and you can get one time coverage with two sets of octagons.  But maybe this doesn't meet your needs.

Comment: I have rechecked my work: the projection of the diagonal onto the horizontal or vertical is 0.75, this gives the width or height as 2.5 units. Thus, the octagonal area is 5.125. Though the area of interest is the repeat unit, which is 49 / 4. This corresponds with the 49 layers (7 x 7), which I mistakenly wrote as 47 before. I had met the tesselation of squares before, but thanks for the theoretical insight.

Comment: You are correct, the octagon is $\frac {41}8$ and the repeat area is $\frac {49}8$.  I agree with your coverage, then.